# call valuefactory in concurrent dictionary in async way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrentdictionary

I am new to C#'s `ConcurrentDictionary` class, and I wonder how I can use a valueFactory in the `GetOrAdd` method in an async way.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int X = 10;

    public Class1(int x)
    {
        X = x;
        Debug.WriteLine("Class1 Created");
    }
}
```

Testing code logic in a WinForm button:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var asyncDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task<Class1>>();

    Func<int, Task<Class1>> valueFactoryAsync = async (k) => new Class1(await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Async Factory Called");
        return 5;
    }));

    var temp = await(asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactoryAsync)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine(temp.X);
    temp.X = 20;
    var temp2 = await (asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactoryAsync)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine(temp2.X);
}
```

When GetOrAdd method is called in the second time, it returns a Task from the concurrent dictionary. Then I called await on the Task,
`var temp2 = await (asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1,valueFactoryAsync)).ConfigureAwait(false);`
it seems like the underlying Task(or async method) was not called again and return a new Class1 object.Was it just returned the Class1 object generated in the first call? 
Could you advise what is happening under the hood?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you asking whether the instance you get on the first call is the same instance you get on the second call? That's quite easy to figure out, isn't it? Or are you asking something else...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get the same instance when you call `asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1,valueFactoryAsync)` the second time. Why does that surprise you? You have provided the same key as in the first time.

> what is happening under the hood?

```
var temp = await(asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactoryAsync)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When this line is called, there is no item in the dictionary for key=1, so `valueFactoryAsync` is called, returns a Task with Status=Created, and this Task is added to the dictionary. That's it for the `Add` part. Now begins the `Get` part, and you get back that new ready-to-run Task. You actually **awaits** this task (`var temp = await (...)`), so the Task begins and your next lines of code won't execute until this Task is done. I hope the rest is quite straightforward from here - the next time you call `await (asyncDict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactoryAsync))` - for `temp2` - there is already an item in the dictionary for this key - a completed Task, and that's the Task you get. Note, that even if you weren't await the first call, the dictionary would still had been populated with `Created` Task, and on the second call you still get the same Task (and hence the same `Class1` instance if you `await` / `.Result` it)

Answer (score 0):

`shay__` already explained a lot. I want to sensitize you for the fact that `GetOrAdd` can call the value factory multiple times for the same key. You don't seem to want that. The standard pattern to avoid that is to use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>`. Here, `TValue = Task<Class1>`. That way only one task will ever be spawned.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is completely unaware of tasks and await.